# chart js + typescript leading to Can't resolve 'react-server-dom-webpack'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chart.js, web-developer-toolbar

Here is my page.tsx file

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from './page.module.css'
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

import {Line} from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { ChartData } from 'chart.js';



export default function Home() {
  const data: ChartData<'line', number[], string> = {
    labels: ['0.5', '1', '1.5', '2', '2.5', '3', '3.5'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'My First dataset',
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,0.4)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
        borderDash: [],
        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
        borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
        pointBorderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
        pointBackgroundColor: '#fff',
        pointBorderWidth: 1,
        pointHoverRadius: 5,
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
        pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: 1,
        pointHitRadius: 10,
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
      }
    ]
  };
  function handleFirebase(): number {
    return 1

  }
  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
   

<nav className="bg-white px-2 sm:px-4 py-2.5 dark:bg-gray-900 fixed w-full z-20 top-0 left-0 border-b border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-600">
  <div className="container flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between mx-auto">
  <a href="https://flowbite.com/" className="flex items-center">
      <span className="self-center text-xl font-semibold whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">Water</span>
  </a>

  <div className="items-center justify-between hidden w-full md:flex md:w-auto md:order-1" id="navbar-sticky">
    <ul className="flex flex-col p-4 mt-4 border border-gray-100 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 md:flex-row md:space-x-8 md:mt-0 md:text-sm md:font-medium md:border-0 md:bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 md:dark:bg-gray-900 dark:border-gray-700">
      <li>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" className="block py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-gray-700 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 md:dark:hover:text-white dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent dark:border-gray-700">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
      
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div className="flex md:order-2 left-10">
  <div className="relative w-full lg:max-w-sm left-10">
            <select className="w-full p-6 text-gray-500 bg-white border rounded-md shadow-sm outline-none appearance-none focus:border-indigo-600 left-10">
                <option>Home</option>
                <option>Work</option>
                <option>School</option>
                <option>Balls</option>
            </select>
        </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Line Example</h2>
    <Line
      data={data}
      width={400}
      height={400}
    />
  </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

Here is my ./node_modules/react-chartjs-2/dist/index.js

```
import { Chart as Chart$1, LineController, BarController, RadarController, DoughnutController, PolarAreaController, BubbleController, PieController, ScatterController } from 'chart.js';

// Import `useClient` from `react-server-dom-webpack`

const defaultDatasetIdKey = "label";

function reforwardRef(ref, value) {
  if (typeof ref === "function") {
    ref(value);
  } else if (ref) {
    ref.current = value;
  }
}

function setOptions(chart, nextOptions) {
  const options = chart.options;
  if (options && nextOptions) {
    Object.assign(options, nextOptions);
  }
}

function setLabels(currentData, nextLabels) {
  currentData.labels = nextLabels;
}

function setDatasets(currentData, nextDatasets, datasetIdKey = defaultDatasetIdKey) {
  const addedDatasets = [];
  currentData.datasets = nextDatasets.map((nextDataset) => {
    // given the new set, find it's current match
    const currentDataset = currentData.datasets.find((dataset) => dataset[datasetIdKey] === nextDataset[datasetIdKey]);
    // There is no original to update, so simply add new one
    if (!currentDataset || !nextDataset.data || addedDatasets.includes(currentDataset)) {
      return {
        ...nextDataset
      };
    }
    addedDatasets.push(currentDataset);
    Object.assign(currentDataset, nextDataset);
    return currentDataset;
  });
}

function cloneData(data, datasetIdKey = defaultDatasetIdKey) {
  const nextData = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: []
  };
  setLabels(nextData, data.labels);
  setDatasets(nextData, data.datasets, datasetIdKey);
  return nextData;
}

/**
 * Get dataset from mouse click event
 * @param chart - Chart.js instance
 * @param event - Mouse click event
 * @returns Dataset
 */
function getDatasetAtEvent(chart, event) {
  return chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(event.nativeEvent, "dataset", {
    intersect: true
  }, false);
}
/**
 * Get single dataset element from mouse click event
 * @param chart - Chart.js instance
 * @param event - Mouse click event
 * @returns Dataset
 */ function getElementAtEvent(chart, event) {
    return chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(event.nativeEvent, "nearest", {
        intersect: true
    }, false);
}
/**
 * Get all dataset elements from mouse click event
 * @param chart - Chart.js instance
 * @param event - Mouse click event
 * @returns Dataset
 */ function getElementsAtEvent(chart, event) {
    return chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(event.nativeEvent, "index", {
        intersect: true
    }, false);
}

function ChartComponent(props, ref) {
    const { height =150 , width =300 , redraw =false , datasetIdKey , type , data , options , plugins =[] , fallbackContent , updateMode , ...canvasProps } = props;
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);
    const chartRef = useRef();
    const renderChart = ()=>{
        if (!canvasRef.current) return;
        chartRef.current = new Chart$1(canvasRef.current, {
            type,
            data: cloneData(data, datasetIdKey),
            options: options && {
                ...options
            },
            plugins
        });
        reforwardRef(ref, chartRef.current);
    };
    const destroyChart = ()=>{
        reforwardRef(ref, null);
        if (chartRef.current) {
            chartRef.current.destroy();
            chartRef.current = null;
        }
    };
    useEffect(()=>{
        if (!redraw && chartRef.current && options) {
            setOptions(chartRef.current, options);
        }
    }, [
        redraw,
        options
    ]);
    useEffect(()=>{
        if (!redraw && chartRef.current) {
            setLabels(chartRef.current.config.data, data.labels);
        }
    }, [
        redraw,
        data.labels
    ]);
    useEffect(()=>{
        if (!redraw && chartRef.current && data.datasets) {
            setDatasets(chartRef.current.config.data, data.datasets, datasetIdKey);
        }
    }, [
        redraw,
        data.datasets
    ]);
    useEffect(()=>{
        if (!chartRef.current) return;
        if (redraw) {
            destroyChart();
            setTimeout(renderChart);
        } else {
            chartRef.current.update(updateMode);
        }
    }, [
        redraw,
        options,
        data.labels,
        data.datasets,
        updateMode
    ]);
    useEffect(()=>{
        if (!chartRef.current) return;
        destroyChart();
        setTimeout(renderChart);
    }, [
        type
    ]);
    useEffect(()=>{
        renderChart();
        return ()=>destroyChart();
    }, []);
    return /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement("canvas", Object.assign({
        ref: canvasRef,
        role: "img",
        height: height,
        width: width
    }, canvasProps), fallbackContent);
}
const Chart = /*#__PURE__*/ forwardRef(ChartComponent);

function createTypedChart(type, registerables) {
    Chart$1.register(registerables);
    return /*#__PURE__*/ forwardRef((props, ref)=>/*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(Chart, Object.assign({}, props, {
            ref: ref,
            type: type
        })));
}
const Line = /* #__PURE__ */ createTypedChart("line", LineController);
const Bar = /* #__PURE__ */ createTypedChart("bar", BarController);
const Radar = /* #__PURE__ */ createTypedChart("radar", RadarController);
const Doughnut = /* #__PURE__ */ createTypedChart("doughnut", DoughnutController);
const PolarArea = /* #__PURE__ */ createTypedChart("polarArea", PolarAreaController);
const Bubble = /* #__PURE__ */ createTypedChart("bubble", BubbleController);
const Pie = /* #__PURE__ */ createTypedChart("pie", PieController);
const Scatter = /* #__PURE__ */ createTypedChart("scatter", ScatterController);

export { Bar, Bubble, Chart, Doughnut, Line, Pie, PolarArea, Radar, Scatter, getDatasetAtEvent, getElementAtEvent, getElementsAtEvent };
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

After running npm run dev I get this error
` Failed to compile
./node_modules/react-chartjs-2/dist/index.js:4:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-server-dom-webpack'

Import trace for requested module:
./src/app/page.tsx

[https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found`](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found%60)
Im attempting to make a chart render on my page.tsx file and im not really sure what index.js does so right now im assuming its auto generated by chart.js. Im currently attempting to make a line chart render with the respective data points in the const data

Answer (score 0):

Below are the possibilities,

- Try with downgrade chartjs version to 3.x.x
- Install types also like @types/react-server-dom-webpack
- Do npm i properly if any of module pending

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are using the relatively latest node version and npm version. Otherwise, edit your question and let us know what versions are you using and on which OS.

Based on my assumptions: since you have commented out the line: `Import useClient from react-server-dom-webpack`

That is the reason why you are getting this error. The npm can not find this module you have commented out. I suggest you do the below:

1. Remove your node modules folder then install npm packages again
2. After that, re-install the dependency by running: `npm install react-dom react`
3. Run your code `npm run start`